# Get all directory from WebDAV server with Jackrabbit library

Tags: java, performance, webdav, jackrabbit

I am writing a recursive method to get all the directories from a WebDAV server:

```
public static void getListFolder(List<String> listFolders, String url) throws Exception {
    HttpPropfind request = new HttpPropfind(url, DavConstants.PROPFIND_ALL_PROP, DavConstants.DEPTH_1);
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request, context)) {
        MultiStatus multiStatus = request.getResponseBodyAsMultiStatus(response);
        MultiStatusResponse[] responses = multiStatus.getResponses();
        if (responses.length > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < responses.length; i++) {
                String href = responses[i].getHref().replace(getRootPath(), "");
                if (href.endsWith("/") && !href.contains("/.")) {
                    listFolders.add(href);
                    getListFolder(listFolders, ROOT_URL + href);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it takes quite long.
So my question is: Is there a quicker and easier way to get all the directories ?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You can try depth infinity, but you'll have to be prepared for servers not supporting it.

Also: why do you use "DavConstants.PROPFIND_ALL_PROP" when all you're interested in are the URIs?

FWIW, you are also making an assumption of ordering in the response body which might lead to surprising results. Also, relying on trailing slashes might be a bad idea; you really should use the DAV:resourcetype property.

Comment: I tried with depth infinity, but it's forbidden 403, cannot get responses

Comment: I optimize this function as some point as you suggest the result is better, thank you